# Appropriate way to use slice of sync.Mutex

Tags: go, mutex

I have recently finished the tour of golang and have tried to reproduce an exercise to increment value of map key using sync.Mutex. I have created one mutex for each key using `[]sync.Mutex` slice. When I run the code, I get an error message of concurrent map writes. What am I doing wrong in the code below?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type SafeUpdate struct {
    s map[string]int
    m []sync.Mutex
}

func (su *SafeUpdate) Inc (key string, idx int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    su.m[idx].Lock()
    defer su.m[idx].Unlock()

    su.s[key]++
}

func main() {
    su := SafeUpdate{s: make(map[string]int), m : make([]sync.Mutex, 3)}
    keymap := map[int]string{0: "zero", 1: "one", 2: "two"}
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go su.Inc(keymap[i%3], i%3, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(su)
}
```

sample error stack:

```
fatal error: concurrent map writes

goroutine 38 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x4c3a62, 0x15)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1116 +0x72 fp=0xc0000c46f0 sp=0xc0000c46c0 pc=0x42f2d2
runtime.mapassign_faststr(0x4a7ae0, 0xc000098150, 0x4c11c6, 0x3, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/map_faststr.go:211 +0x3f7 fp=0xc0000c4758 sp=0xc0000c46f0 pc=0x4107e7
main.(*SafeUpdate).Inc(0xc0000ac020, 0x4c11c6, 0x3, 0x2, 0xc0000b6010)
    /home/afrozalm/Project/goLang/keyMutex.go:19 +0xe6 fp=0xc0000c47b8 sp=0xc0000c4758 pc=0x491cc6
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1373 +0x1 fp=0xc0000c47c0 sp=0xc0000c47b8 pc=0x45be81
created by main.main
    /home/afrozalm/Project/goLang/keyMutex.go:29 +0x2be

.
.
.
```

Comment: There is no error in the message you provided.

Comment: `su.s[key]++` -- this expression is run concurrently and must be synchronised. If you want to mutate map - you must block so that only one goroutine was doing it at the moment.

Comment: @zerkms I understand what I am doing wrong. I should not treat the map as being made up of distinct part of keys but map as a whole. Thanks